# Where can I get an XSD that defines the Clover XML schema?

Tags: clover

I have tried Atlassian Clover docs, but I can only find info on the Ant build XML specification.  I am sure the information is there, but I am struggling to find it.  Alternatively, an example of a modular Clover XML file would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Clover-for-Ant ZIP file (http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/download) and unpack it. Schema is in etc\clover.xsd.

Comment: As of 2022 you can download the schema directly from the [Clover repository](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/clover/src/master/): https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/clover/raw/master/etc/schema/clover.xsd